# upload form to database using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to code for uploading data from form plus upload file to a server path using PHP. In this I am able to achieve the functionality of uploading files and data but in this I wanted to add one more feature where, if email already exist then a warning should be thrown that "email already exist" and pnly pdf file should be accepted. I tried some coding but it does not work.

Can any guru add code block to the below code to achieve the functionality of unique email id and restrict file type to only pdf.

```
    <?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
     $name = trim($_POST["uname"]);
     $email = trim($_POST["uemail"]);
     $exp = trim($_POST["uexp"]);
     $desig = trim($_POST["udesig"]);
     $tech = trim($_POST["utech"]); 


    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);    

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))

    {

        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name,email,exp,desig,tech,file,type,size) VALUES('$name','$email','$exp','$desig','$tech','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>

        window.location.href='success.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Make sure to make the email either the primary key in the db table or give it a `unique` constraint in the table schema, and not just try and enforce this via php.

Comment: I already have serial number as primary and unique constraint. Hence was trying to enforce from php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from tbl_uploads where email = :email_id";
try {
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    //only grabbing one row so use fetch instead of fetchAll
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    /*
    *check if result is an array
    *check is count exists in the array
    * check if result['count'] gt 0
    */
    if (is_array($result) && array_key_exists('count', $result) && $result["count"] > 0) {
        $msg = "Email already exist";
        $msgType = "warning";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to count rows, in your case change to:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($result) > 0) {
   $msg = "Email already exist";
   $msgType = "warning";
}
```

or using `fetch()`

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $msg = "Email already exist";
  $msgType = "warning";
}
```

or without fetching:

```
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
  $msg = "Email already exist";
  $msgType = "warning";
}
```

or since `PHP` is loosely typed perhaps you just needed to cast it to an integer:

```
if ((int)$result[0]["count"] > 0)
```